# calculate inputed numbers from textboxes

Tags: php, html

My mission to my program is when a record filtered in the textboxes if i change the numbers it will automatically change the total and calculate in the (total)textbox...can anyone help me whats wrong with my code? I porposely dont loop the textboxes because i have plans on it.

html code:

```
<form id="frm" name="frm" />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Name: <br />
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(empty($name[0])){$name[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $name[0];} ?>" readonly onClick="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 1: <br />
<input type="text" name="optA" value="<?php if(empty($score1[0])){$score1[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score1[0];} ?>" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" onClick="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 2: <br />
<input type="text" name="optB" value="<?php if(empty($score2[0])){$score2[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score2[0];} ?>" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" onClick="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 3: <br />
<input type="text" name="optC" value="<?php if(empty($score3[0])){$score3[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score3[0];} ?>" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" onClick="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 4: <br />
<input type="text" name="optD" value="<?php if(empty($score4[0])){$score4[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score4[0];} ?>" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" onClick="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Total: <br />
<input type="text" name="total" value="<?php if(empty($total[0])){$total[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $total[0];} ?>" readonly onKeyUp="optTotal()" /> <br />
</td>
</form>
```

script to total:

```
<script>
function optTotal()
{
    var a1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optA"]');
    var b1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optB"]');
    var c1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optC"]');
    var d1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optD"]');

    if (a1.value && a1.value != "")
        a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
    else
        a1 = 0;

    if (b1.value && b1.value != "")
        b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
    else
        b1 = 0;

    if (c1.value && c1.value != "")
        c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
    else
        c1 = 0;

    if (d1.value && d1.value != "")
        d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
    else
        d1 = 0;

      document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(a1)+parseFloat(b1)+parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(d1);

}
</script>
```

The problem is its not calculating if i change the numbers on the textboxes on(optA)to(optD).

Comment: Please mention your correct problem ?

Comment: @Anand Somasekhar The problem is the its not calculating if i change the numbers on the textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this on onchange event

```
 function optTotal() {
        var a1 = document.forms[0].optA;
        var b1 = document.forms[0].optB;
        var c1 = document.forms[0].optC;
        var d1 = document.forms[0].optD;
        if (a1.value && a1.value != "")
            a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
        else
            a1 = 0;

        if (b1.value && b1.value != "")
            b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
        else
            b1 = 0;

        if (c1.value && c1.value != "")
            c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
        else
            c1 = 0;

        if (d1.value && d1.value != "")
            d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
        else
            d1 = 0;


        var total = a1 + b1 + c1+d1;
        document.forms[0].total.value = total;
      }
```